# How to maintain a dropdown list on form post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `View` that allows users to select an item from a dropdown list, which is then POSTed to the `Controller`. The `ViewModel` has properties for the list of dropdown items and the selected item. Everything works fine, except I want to retain the list after the form POST.

I think I could facilitate the model binding by generating hidden fields for the list, but that seems messy. What is a clean way to achieve this? Thanks.

Here's the relevant code:

#### ViewModel

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public List<UserLocationViewModel> Locations { get; set; }

    public class UserLocationViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### View

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LocationId,
                      new SelectList(Model.Locations, "Id", "Name"), 
                      "-- Select Location --"))
```

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateUserViewModel model)
```

**EDIT**

The scenario is posting a form within a modal dialog via ajax, where I need validation to happen in the controller, but be able to retain the state of the viewmodel so I can show the validation stuff on the modal form. I have this working but currently need to repopulate the lists before returning the model on failed validation.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "retain the list after the form POST" and confirm whether or not the Post action is submitted via ajax.

Comment: The scenario is posting a form within a modal dialog via ajax, where I need validation to happen in the controller, but be able to retain the state of the viewmodel so I can show the validation stuff on the modal.

Comment: Ok thanks - I think you'll probably need some more code in the question - at least the ajax script - and what you're doing with the returned data

Comment: If you posting by ajax, then you can just return a `JsonResult` containing the `ModelState` errors and update the DOM. But you cannot 'retain the list' unless you were to generate a form control for each property of each `SelectListItem` in the collection which would be just crazy. Get it again in the controller like everyone else does!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was trying to avoid hitting the database again, but I guess that's reasonable. Maybe the answer is caching the list inside the viewmodel somehow.

Comment: Why? That is what databases are for. To generate all the extra html, send it all across the wire, then send it all back again unchanged is crazy. And if you have set up client side validation then 99% of the time you will not need it anyway. And if its data that does not change often, then store it in `MemoryCache`

Comment: I'm trying to do all validation using the viewmodel data annotations and thought that required hitting the controller, but it seems that's incorrect and I can validate using jquery before doing any further processing.

Comment: Client side validation is all done automatically assuming you have included the validation scripts and not disabled client side validation.